# Insert a cell with a Basic Macro in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: basic, libreoffice-calc, uno

I'm trying to insert a cell beginning with the first cell in a range (via the .getCellRangeByName() method of a Document's active Sheet).

I found out how to do this with a Dispatcher from the OpenOffice library (.uno:InsertCell), but I'd prefer to use something that doesn't require the dispatcher if possible.

Example code that I plan to wire-up to a button...

```
Sub AddManualBalance(EntryDate As Date, EntryAmount As Currency)

    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Doc = ThisComponent
    If Doc Is Nothing Then
        Return
    EndIf
    Sheet = Doc.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        Return
    EndIf

    Dim TargetCells As Object
    TargetCells = Sheet.getCellRangeByName("B9:C9");

    // insert a cell in both the B and C columns at position 9,
    // then move all other cells down

    // add my EntryDate as a value to the new cell in B column
    // add my EntryAmount as a value to the new cell in C column

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. I really dislike Basic, but it seems that with spreadsheets and office app automation, that's the preferred language. Is there any way to do LibreOffice/OpenOffice macros in a more C-like language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code does what you want:

```
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Sheet As Object
Dim oDestCell As Object
Dim CellRangeAddress As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress

Doc = ThisComponent
Sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)

CellRangeAddress.Sheet = 0
CellRangeAddress.StartColumn = 1
CellRangeAddress.StartRow = 8
CellRangeAddress.EndColumn = 2
CellRangeAddress.EndRow = 8

Sheet.insertCells(CellRangeAddress, com.sun.star.sheet.CellInsertMode.DOWN)

oDestCell=Sheet.getCellByPosition(1,8)
oDestCell.setValue(EntryDate)

oDestCell=Sheet.getCellByPosition(2,8)
oDestCell.setValue(EntryAmount)
```

You can read about C++ and LibreOffice at api.libreoffice.org

Comment: Thanks! Your code helped me get to where I wanted to go. I changed it to match my code, and will answer my own question below thanks to your help. However, the API in C++ doesn't really help me, since I want an alternative macro language, not to edit LibreOffice itself. I found that you can add javascript to Calc, but not sure if this works like a macro or not, and if you can use javascript to write new functions usable in cells, like you can with Basic (eg: function MYFUNC(parm1 as object, parm2...))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mac, my code is now...

```
Public Doc As Object
Public Sheet As Object

Sub AddManualBalance()

    GetCurrentSheet()

    REM insert two new cells, move cells down
    Dim TargetCells As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
    TargetCells.Sheet = 3
    TargetCells.StartColumn = 1
    TargetCells.StartRow = 8
    TargetCells.EndColumn = 2
    TargetCells.EndRow = 8
    Sheet.insertCells(TargetCells, com.sun.star.sheet.CellInsertMode.DOWN)

    REM get date and balance from text boxes, add value to cells
    Dim BalanceDate As Object
    Dim BalanceAmount As Object
    Dim Forms As Object
    Dim MainForm As Object
    Forms = Doc.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet().getDrawPage().getForms()
    MainForm = Forms("MainForm")
    BalanceDate = MainForm.getByName("BalanceDate")
    BalanceAmount = MainForm.getByName("BalanceAmount")
    Sheet.getCellByPosition(1,8).setValue(BalanceDate.CurrentValue)
    Sheet.getCellByPosition(2,8).setValue(BalanceAmount.CurrentValue)

End Sub

Sub GetCurrentSheet()

    REM get references to document and active sheet, test if exist
    If ThisComponent Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    Doc = ThisComponent
    If Doc Is Nothing Then
        Return
    EndIf
    Sheet = Doc.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()

End Sub
```